# very slow wordpress query with default query

Tags: query

I had been asking questions about this issue but sadly not getting the help
blog at this address : http://fixapk.com
Currently, the blog includes approximately 560,000 apps ( 560,000 equivalent posts)
each article covers about 20 custom fields
therefore wp_postmeta table is the largest table ( with about 10 million records )
However, when the query to the table wp_postmeta very good for speed , for example :
When access to the single post the query related articles based on the title , the speed is very good ( you can access on an article to see any speed )
Or : When using the search function shows good speed ( not the best)
But when access to the category , the speed is really slow
for example, when accessing the APPS category ( fixapk.com/apps ) or GAMES ( fixapk.com/games ) , the speed is too slow
Category apps has about 300k posts .
This means that the default wordpress query very slow ( query base on category )
and here is the content of the file archive.php

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="content">
    <?php
        if (have_posts()):while(have_posts()):the_post();
        $numdown=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_numdown',true);
        $icon=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_icon',true);
        $screenshot=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_screenshot',true);
        $language=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_language',true);
        $licesne=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_licesne',true);
        $os=get_post_meta($post->ID,'_os',true);
        //....
    ?>
    <div class="item item-apps">
        <img src="<?php echo $icon; ?>" /> <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        <?php the_excerpt(); //.....?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thus, how to replace the default query to speed wordpress
Look forward to the help

Comment: do you use any sort of caching?

Comment: i use apc on vps. On query i don't use anything caching query

Comment: Who's help me? ...hix